# How to load a javascript code only once when open new window

Tags: javascript

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    $('.progress-start').css({'display': "none"});
});
```

I want to show progress bar once when open new window. But when i redict to different url progress again loading.

I tryed to set cookie but not working

Comment: Maybe you should show the failed cookie attempt ..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to persist some data across new window/new tab load you can use `sessionStorage` or If you want to persist some data on browser load you can use `localStorage`.

In your case, if you want to hide progress bar on redirect to different URLs of your website on the same window then you should use `sessionStorage`. If you're using jquery then you can go something like this:

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
    // Retrieve progress bar status, if it is undefined give its default status to false
    var loadedProgress = sessionStorage.getItem('loadedProgress') || false;

    // check if progress is already loaded
    // If it is already loaded don't show it again
    // Otherwise show progress bar and set an indicator in session storage about it.
    if(loadedProgress){
      $('.progress-start').css({'display': "none"});
    }else{
      $('.progress-start').css({'display': "block"});
      sessionStorage.setItem('loadedProgress', true);
    }
});
```

Here I built a quick demo for you https://codepen.io/abhishekraj/pen/JMerje

In this demo when you load for first time, `loading...` text will show but when you load it for second time loading text won't show. Try to open in new window to check its behavior.

Answer (score 0):

When you redirect to a different URL, the browser throws away all of your JavaScript context and starts from scratch in the new page.

You can use [`sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) as a way to save some state and load it in the new page. This is generally much easier than using cookies.